# Automatically keep texture's ratio and texture's size when repeating

Tags: three.js

I'm using three.js to build a house, i have walls and textures for walls.

Walls are basically CubeGeometry.

I took a unique scale : 1cm = 1px

textures could be bricks or any other construction materials, but textures files are always 512x512 with details in it. for example : One brick in the texture file will be 10px per 4px.

I need to keep this ratio to keep the reality of the scene.

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/wall.jpg");

texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

texture.repeat = new THREE.Vector2(0.2 , 0.2);

var wall = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }));
```

that's works quite well because the case is simple ;), it is also very simple to made a ratio for every walls (which can have any sort of sizes)

But in fact i have plenty of other geometries (procedurally generated and so on), is there by any chance a property like : "THREE.KeepMyTextureSizeAndRepeat" wrapping ? Or will i need to make ratios for each of my custom geometries ?

If you have any advice on this use case, i will be greatfull :)

Many thanks

EDIT : the final goal is to do something like "patterns" in 2D canvas

```
var pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, repeatOption);
context.fillStyle = pattern;
context.fill();
```

when you do something like that, on a rect for example the pattern will be repeated keeping the aspect ratio (e.g http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-patterns-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to calculate every ratio by yourself because a texture doesn't know anything about the pixels. It only knows about the uvs.

Comment: thanks for your answer, in fact i was asking because i thought when you use CLAMP_TO_EDGE for wrapping, the texture will be rendered knowing about the pixels ? isn't it ?

Comment: nope when using Clampto edge it will copy only the last pixel instead of the whole picture

Comment: i think i was confusing in my question, so i modified it. But what i understand is it will not be possible in a simple way... i will made calculus :(